# How do I make a horizontally stretchable background in android

Tags: java, android, xml, background, nine-patch

I want to make a button background like this

[image]

So that when the content gets longer the background only gets stretched form the central region and the circular sides stay CIRCULAR.

[image]

I tried to make a 9-patch without a vertical stretch region but the circular sides went oval like in different sizes as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

when I specify a vertical stretch region in the center, the background becomes like this which I don't want it to. this is an square with rounded corners.

[image]

I also have to say that this background is basically a pink border which has a pink drop shadow both on the inside and the outside. I couldn't find a way to implement this with android drawable as there is no efficient way to have a good shadow effect using it

I can't think of a clean solution for doing so. please help me.

Comment: Your problem seems unclear to understand. Do you want the pic1 and pic2 but you design is giving you pic3 and pic4 result. Is it so?

Comment: @MuhammadFarhanArif yes 1 and 2 is what I want. 3 and 4 was what I could achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I just made a custom view that extends `FrameLayout` and it has a customizable colored shadow and stroke.

You can also use it to draw an inner background in the center.

[image] [image]

you can add it in your project from my GitHub page.

https://github.com/mr-sarsarabi/NeonLightBackgroundLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use the rectangle shape  in xml drawable and keep the radius to max.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#A5A5A5" />
    <corners android:radius="999dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: This is actually working for making the border but what about the drop shadow? as you can see there is a little glowing effect around it. how can I implement that?